# A method to get The last Time a File was Opened in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to get the last time a file was opened in Google Drive(Not Modified) via Apps Script.
I read [the Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive) but did not find anything similar. I do know that the last opened is being kept track of as it is available in Google Drive [image: Drive Last Opened]

I think there might be a way to add a Opened property to all the files in Drive but I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This would only be possible within a Workspace domain.

There is nothing in the Apps Script `DriveApp` as you have seen.

Even within the Drive API (accessible from Apps Script with the [advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)), the closest thing you have is:

```json
{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": string,
  "createdDate": datetime,
  "modifiedDate": datetime,
  "modifiedByMeDate": datetime,
  "lastViewedByMeDate": datetime,
  "markedViewedByMeDate": datetime
}
```

So it will only get you the date that *you* viewed/opened it.

If all the users were within the same Workspace account, you can use [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account). You would use the service account to impersonate all of the users and get the `lastViewedByMeDate` for each user.

A similar thing is possible with Aapps Script, but again within a Workspace Domain. Using the `onOpen` trigger, if you look at the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) there is the possibility to get the active user. Note that this will *not* work for Gmail accounts.

#### References

- [Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)
- [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)
- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)